# Emacs php-mode font-lock properties are not applied to certain chars

Tags: regex, emacs, lisp, php-mode, font-lock

For example variable dollar signs.

php-mode.el line 1087:

```
'("\\$\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)" (1 font-lock-variable-name-face)) ; $variable
```

If I'm not mistaken the regexp should match $variable including the dollar sign.
Now, i'm trying to figure out why isn't the font-lock property applied to the dollar sign also.
In the syntax table $ is considered a word just like A-z.

So i guess what i'm trying to ask is:
Did anyone experienced the same problem and has he/she found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1` in there means match the first capture group denoted by (escaped) parens.  The `$` is outside that capture group.  So it could either be moved inside, or change the `1` to a `0` which means use the entire regexp.